# operating on an element after genereting it with post() in jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to make a table with an instant search with input fields which are generated by the post() action and I want jQuery to recognize it but the problem is I'm stuck with "ready" action so I can't operate on new items like this one.

```
$(document).ready(
    function() { 
        $.post("trier.php",{trier: name},function(data,status) { 
            $("#aaa").html(data) 
        }); 
        $("#probleme").keyup(
            function() { 
                var name = $("#probleme").val(); 
                $.post(
                    "trier.php",
                    {trier: name},
                    function(data,status) { 
                        $("#aaa").html(data) 
                    }
                ); 
            }
        ); 
    }
);
```

Comment: And by operate, you mean adding event listeners like click?

Comment: no I'm gonna take its value in my case as you can see in here :
var name = $("#probleme").val();
there's gonna be an input field generated from the $.post and I want to use that for later work

Comment: Can you give a sample code of how you are going to operate and where you are putting that code?

Comment: that's the code I'm gonna operate with actually. it's gonna take the value of the input field with "probleme" ID and it's gonna send it again to $.post

Comment: Does `#probleme` exist only in your post response?

Comment: yes: echo "<td><input type="text" id="probleme"></td>";

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: Yesss thank you so much @LouysPatriceBessette that's what I was looking for I suck at explaining.